# PHP: How to insert <br> when a space is recognized?

Tags: php, newline, whitespace, line-breaks

I have a series of coordinates (lat1,long1 lat2,long2 lat3,long3...)

`121.01953125,14.6893901824952 121.019706726075,14.6893205642702 121.019889831543,14.6891403198242 121.020111083984,14.688931465149 121.020446777344,14.6887502670288 121.020835876465,14.6887207031249`

What I want to do is enter a line break or 'br' whenever a space is recognized/detected so it becomes...

```
121.01953125,14.6893901824952 
121.019706726075,14.6893205642702 
121.019889831543,14.6891403198242 
121.020111083984,14.688931465149 
121.020446777344,14.6887502670288 
121.020835876465,14.6887207031249
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I tried the solutions that they suggested, but it isn't working.

```
echo str_replace(" ","<br />",$string);
```

My string is from a kml file and when I echo the string, it's like the one I've stated above. I'm using the following code to parse the file.

```
$string = $placemark->MultiGeometry->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
echo str_replace(' ', '<br />', $yourCoordinates);
```

Comment: You are faster than I

Comment: Hi! I tried this before but it isn't working. My string is from this $yourCoordinates = $placemark->MultiGeometry->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates; It's from a kml file and when I echo the string, it's like the one I've stated above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that your spaces are indeed spaces ? And not, maybe, tabs or newlines ? Check out the 'source' in your browser to see what's going on. If it's a "Real" newline (\n) your browser will show it as a space. Oh, and by the way, if it is some kind of spacing: preg_replace('/\s/', '<br />', $yourCoordinates); should work.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$str = str_replace(" ","<br />",$str);
```

Comment: `<b>` tag? I hope that is a typo =o) Should be `<br />`. *Update:* Better =o)

Answer (score 1):

`echo str_replace(' ', '<br/>', $coordinates);`

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = "121.01953125,14.6893901824952 121.019706726075,14.6893205642702 121.019889831543,14.6891403198242 121.020111083984,14.688931465149 121.020446777344,14.6887502670288 121.020835876465,14.6887207031249";

echo $return = str_replace(" ","<br />",$string);
```

hope this will help to you